# Wer ist ein "Macker"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Dialog aus einem Übungsheft:

> Hast du in letzter Zeit … gesehen?
>
> Nein, **der ist so ein Macker geworden**. Und seine neue Freundin ist eine
> totale Schickse. Die war schon mit fast jedem zusammen.

Ich verstehe das Wort *Macker* nicht ganz. Laut DUDEN ist *der Macker*

Freund (besonders einer jungen Frau)

oder

Bursche, Kerl.

Die angeführten Beispiele sind verständlich:

> das ist ihr neuer Macker
>
> sie kam mit ihrem Macker
>
> was will der Macker hier?

Aber ich verstehe dann den Sinn des oben genannten Satzes nicht. Wie kann man *ein Macker werden*?

Comment: Dasselbe wie *der Stecher*

Comment: @tofro, in dem Beispiel ja gerade nicht.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macker) beschreibt es recht gut:

> Der Begriff Macker (aus dem Niederdeutschen: macker „Kamerad“, „Mitarbeiter“; im Niederländischen: makker) wird umgangssprachlich bisweilen als abwertende Bezeichnung für einen Mann verwendet, der sich übertrieben männlich darstellt und ist daher inhaltlich mit Begriffen wie Chauvi oder Macho verwandt. Er kann aber auch neutral den Lebenspartner oder allgemein einen „Burschen“ oder Arbeitskollegen bezeichnen.

Comment: Die Frage war: "Wie kann man ein Macker werden?" In Deiner Antwort wird das implizit klar, es wäre aber vielleicht doch ein paar Worte wert.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ich finde, so sehr muss man die Leute dann auch wieder nicht ans Händchen nehmen ;) Zusätzlich zur aktuellen Antwort zu erklären, dass man "ein Macker _wird_", wenn man früher das beschriebene Klischee nicht erfüllt hat, es jetzt aber erfüllt, fühlt sich für mich doch ziemlich gönnerhaft an. Aber wenn Du anderer Meinung bist, habe ich auch keine Einwände gegen einen entsprechenden Edit.

Comment: Edits mache ich nur bei meinen eigenen Antworten ;-) Für mich ist der Punkt folgender: Das Wort "Macker" hat verschiedene Interpretationen - neutral im Sinne von Freund, Bursche, Kollege und negativ besetzt im Sinne von Macho o.ä. Serena kannte offensichtlich nur die "neutrale Variante".  In der Formulierung "der ist **so ein** Macker geworden" passt aber gerade die nicht. Ja, beinahe wäre hier "der ist so ein A... geworden" richtig.